# DROP TABLE behaviour in Postgres transactions

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, ddl

Say I'm working on an ETL that periodically reads source data from a CSV and replaces a table in Postgres (9.6).

Here is one approach:

```
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table
CREATE TABLE table (...)
COPY table FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv, HEADER true)
CREATE INDEX ON table (...)
COMMIT
```

Here is another:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE table_temp (...)
COPY table_temp FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv, HEADER true)
CREATE INDEX ON table_temp (...)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table
ALTER TABLE table_temp RENAME TO table
COMMIT
```

Am I correct about the following?

- The first transaction will lock the table at the `DROP` command, so concurrent `SELECT` queries will block until the transaction is complete.
- The second transaction will not block `SELECT` queries until after the `COPY` and `CREATE INDEX` finish.
- Both transactions are atomic: in either case, if I issue a `ROLLBACK` instead of `COMMIT`, the table will be restored with all original data and indexes.

Also, aside from the name of the index, are there any other functional differences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, all 3 of your assumptions are correct.

The end result would be the same in case of both transactions but the blocking caused by the first transaction would be longer and depend on the amount of data and the time it takes to create the index. The 2nd transaction would require a very brief lock to rename the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Some info for people who think that renaming a table will be sufficient for their use case. Beware! Renaming in PostgreSQL may not work as you expected sometimes.

More info here [What could go wrong, when swapping table contents using table rename in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678956/what-could-go-wrong-when-swapping-table-contents-using-table-rename-in-postgres)