# What could go wrong, when swapping table contents using table rename in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I need to atomically change big number of rows in a Postgresql table. I'm using the technique like this: add data to a temporary table and then swap tables by renaming original to not_matter_name and temp to original name. The technique is described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100779/how-to-atomically-replace-table-data-in-postgresql).

But this approach is broken. For example, I found that views do not update pointers to new table and still point to the old table even after name swap. The only solution I found was to recreate views, which is a bit awful.

What else except problem with views could go wrong with such a technique?

Am I doing something wrong overall? Is there any better solution to swap tables fast, which doesn't cause side effects like this on other Postgresql entities?

---

The code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE _temp_with_updated_data (like original_name including all);

--...MANY INSERTS TO _temp_with_updated_data

begin;
alter table original_name rename to ___doesnt_matter;
alter table _temp_with_updated_data rename to original_name;
alter table ___doesnt_matter to _temp_with_updated_data;
truncate table _temp_with_updated_data;
commit;
```

Comment: DDL changes are transaction safe in PostgreSQL, so you should be good there. No need for `__doesnt_matter`, Don't forget your indexes on the new table! With a flip of a transactional switch, your query performance will hit the floor if you forget. Also a DROP and re-CREATE TABLE is faster than a TRUNCATE, but that's up to your use case.

Comment: I see that `__doesnt_matter` was essentially a temp variable. I meant that it wouldn't be needed if you followed the DROP->re-CREATE TABLE route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What else except problem with views could go wrong with such a technique?

1. Any other objects dependencies. For example,

   - Sequences "owned by" the table.
   - Publications and subscriptions
   - Triggers.
2. You could encounter transient errors *relation with oid XXX does not exist*.
3. If the table is partitioned/inherited, subpartitions will be locked too.

I would seriously consider to use  DELETE / INSERT pattern instead of RENAME / TRUNCATE pattern.

Especially if your future plans include partitioning, logical or trigger-based replication.

Comment: Thx @filiprem, it's a pitty Postgres doesn't support lighweight no-hassle data swap. I probably will use DELETE/INSERT as you suggest despite the fact, that it will increase bloat and pressure on auto-vacuum routine. I'd like to use truncate instead of delete, but it hard-locks the whole table which when combined with long inserts is not acceptable. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The other problem (besides views) that springs to mind is foreign keys, if you have them.  They also will follow the original table when it is renamed.  Functions don't have the problem, as they resolve table names when executed, not when created.

If you don't like recreating the views, you could use [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-inherit.html) from an empty base table, and point the views at that.  Then you would NO INHERIT the old one and INHERIT the new one.  Personally I find this cure worse than the disease, and just recreate the views.  You can get the view definitions from `pg_dump -s`, if you don't already have them stashed some place, but you need to sort out for yourself which ones you need.

Another problem might be just a performance one that bulk inserts into an already indexed table can be slow.  You might want to create with INCLUDING ALL EXCLUDING INDEXES, and then build the indexes after it is populated.  Alas, PostgreSQL does not make that second part easy to do.  There is nothing like the hypothetical  ALTER TABLE foo2 INCLUDE INDEXES LIKE foo1 that you can run after the fact (but again, `pg_dump -s` can help here, to get the list of create index statements).  But if the current performance doesn't bother you, then just don't exclude the indexes in the first place and you won't need to build them later.

Comment: Thx for your reply